# Why is second array writing stupid numbers? - C language

Tags: c, arrays, random

I have a little problem creating random numbers in 2 arrays. First array create random numbers fine, but the other one create always same numbers, although it sometimes change them for eg. 10 10 10 10 10 10 etc... but when I run program again it says 7 7 7 7 7 etc..

Here is program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int i,j,switchh,switching;
    int howmany = 10;
    int a[howmany],b[howmany];
    for (i=0;i<howmany;i++) {
        b[i] = rand() % 10+1;
    }
    while(1) {
        switchh=0;
        for (i=0; i<howmany-1;i++) {
            if (b[i]>b[i+1]) {
                int switching=b[i];
                b[i]=b[i+1];
                b[i+1]=switching;
                switchh = 1;
            }
        }
        if(switchh==0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    for (j=0;j<howmany;j++) {
        a[j] = rand() % 10+1;
    }
    while(1) {
        switchh=0;
        for (j=0; j<howmany-1;j++) {
            if (a[j]>a[j+1]) {
                int switching=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=switching;
                switchh = 1;
            }
        }
        if(switchh==0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    for (j=0;j<howmany;j++) {
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<howmany;i++) {
        printf("%d\n",b[i]);
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)

Comment: `for (j=...printf(...a[i]` might be part of your problem.

Comment: Eugene, with one it was doing same thing, added second just for test if something will change. Any suggestions what to change Lee?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker is saying you're using the wrong variable in your second to last `for` loop where you print the contents of `a`. The loop control variable is `j`, but you're printing out `a[i]`.. `i` doesn't change at all in that loop. In fact you're probably invoking UB since I think `i` equals `howmany` at that point, and `a` can only be accessed up to `howmany-1`.

Comment: `main()` should be `int main(void)`

Comment: Why don't you use a function like before, to avoid repeating the same code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Do not call
 `srand ( time(NULL) );` second time. This restarts generator with the same numbers!!

2)  `a[j] = rand() % 10+1;`  The range is limited. If you can increase `10` to `100` or `1000.`

3) Printout is wrong:

```
for (j=0;j<howmany;j++) {
    printf("%d\n",a[i]); // change to a[j];
}
```

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    srand ( time(NULL) );

    int i,j,switchh,switching;
    int howmany = 10;
    int a[howmany],b[howmany];


    for (i=0;i<howmany;i++) {
        b[i] = rand() % 10 +1;
    }

    while(1) 
    {
        switchh=0;
        for (i=0; i<howmany-1;i++) {

            if (b[i]>b[i+1]) {

                int switching=b[i];
                b[i]=b[i+1];
                b[i+1]=switching;
                switchh = 1;
            }
        }

        if(switchh==0) {
            break;
        }
    }

   // srand ( time(NULL) );

    for (j=0;j<howmany;j++) {
        a[j] = rand() % 10+1;
    }

    while(1) {
        switchh=0;
        for (j=0; j<howmany-1;j++) {

            if (a[j]>a[j+1]) {

                int switching=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=switching;
                switchh = 1;
            }
        }
        if(switchh==0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (j=0;j<howmany;j++) {
        printf("%d\n",a[j]);
    }

    printf(" \n");

    for (i=0;i<howmany;i++) {
        printf("%d\n",b[i]);
    }

    return 0;
```

}

Output:

```
1
2
2
3
5
6
7
8
8
9

3
3
4
5
6
6
8
8
9
9
```